# How to set up an NLB to my ALB for using a static ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb

I've got a terraform ECS cluster set up with an ALB for the cluster and it works as expected however I don't want 100% up time and whenever I perform a terraform destroy, I get a new IP address.

Reading [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/) amazon blog, it looks like it's possible to provision a static IP address to an ALB behind an NLB however the resources and modules for ELBs in terraform seem to require an EC2 instance ID so I can't see how to target an ALB instead.

Comment: Why don't you want a new IP address?

Comment: Application needs to be accessible from outside aws and if the IP changes I will need to update the address wherever it is used.

Comment: What's wrong with just using DNS? Or are you restricting outbound traffic on a firewall somewhere?

Comment: The DNS changes too

Comment: You can point a CNAME or ALIAS A record to the ALB which trivially solves this.